# blank page loaded after downloading Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle18c, oracle-apex-18.2

I downloaded Oracle 18C at my Linux Centos machine and it's working fine.After that I downloaded Oracle Apex and followed all the steps but I come across with blank page as most of the people come across after setup of Oracle Apex. Lots of people came across with the problem and I followed all the steps that they mentioned. But I still see blank page when I load http://hostname:8080/apex/apex_admin. I could not find error logs as well neither from browser nor from any apex log directory. 
.

Best Regards